# What are the default values for nrow and ncol in R's matrix function?

Tags: r, matrix, default-value

What are the default values for the arguments `nrow` and `ncol` in the function `matrix` in R?

In order words: By writing

```
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol=2)
```

I can make the function `matrix` automatically calculate how many rows the resulting matrix will have, and the output will be

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
```

However, if I want `ncol` to be a positional argument in this function call and I simply remove `ncol=`, that is

```
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 2)
```

the "`2`" is going to end up as the value of `nrow` and not as the value of `ncol`, and I will instead get the matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

I can fix this by providing the function a value for `nrow` so that the `2` is pushed to its correct position, like so:

```
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 3, 2)
```

and I will get the desired matrix again. I could also use this method of providing a value for `nrow` if I were using a keyword argument for `ncol`, but at the same time wanted to be clear and provide the `nrow` argument as well:

```
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

But now `matrix` doesn't calculate the number of rows for me, but I have to calculate it myself. What value should I write instead of `3` if I want tell `matrix` to calculate the number of rows itself? I've tried replacing the `3` with `NULL`, `None` (usually works in cases like this in Python), and `-1` but these all give me errors (and `0` and `1` give me matrices with 0 rows and 1 row, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

We can place a `,` before

```
 matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ,2)
```

Here, the `,` is placed based on the argument order in the function.  If we check `?matrix`, the usage is

> matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)

Note, that most of the argument have default values.  It is always better to pass function argument with names, but if we want to skip, can use the right number of `,` (also depends on the function behavior).  Here, we can set the `dimnames` as well   after skipping the `byrow` argument with a `,`

```
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ,2, ,list(NULL, c('a', 'b')))
#     a b
#[1,] 1 4
#[2,] 2 5
#[3,] 3 6
```

Comment: Okay, good to know. What value would the `nrow` argument get in this case?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye  It is always based on the order of arguments in the function.  Here, in `?matrix`. if you check the3 usage `matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE,
       dimnames = NULL)` the second argument is nrow, followed by ncol.

Comment: If the arguments are given as positional arguments, yes (if they are given as keyword arguments the order doesn't matter). Which of my questions did you answer now?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye  My suggestion is to use keyword arguments instead of position based as positions can be tricky and prone to mistakes (by either removing one of those commas).  Also, if you are using code for development, other developers may also use your code and may have hard time in understanding what it means

Comment: I agree that using keyword arguments instead of many positional arguments makes the code easier to read. You write in your answer that most arguments have default values—well, do you know what those values are? :) That is still what I'm wondering and what my question is about.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye  If you check the arguments, `data = NA`, i..e if you construct a matrix without data, it would be `NA`, i.e. `matrix(nrow= 2,  ncol = 2)`  Or just by calling `matrix()` it would be `1 row/1 column, `NA`  As the `dimnames` are NULL, there won't be any names

Comment: But it also says `nrow = 1`, which is not the default value for `nrow`. If I use that value, I get a matrix with only one row (I want to get one with three rows).

Comment: @HelloGoodbye You can check `matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)`  What I meant is that if you just call the function without passing any parameters, it would be a `NA` matrix with 1 row/1 column.  Also, the case I mentioned is when you don't provide `ncol`.  If either one of them is provided, it would readjust within the function.  You can check the source code of `matrix`

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I'm after. If I write `matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), , 2)` I get the correct matrix, and omitting one of the arguments means that R uses the default value for that argument. I should be able to insert this default value in the function call instead of leaving the space blank and get the same result, but writing `matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 1, 2)` gives me another matrix than if I leave the space blank (I get a matrix with only one row), so `1` is obviously not the default value for `nrow`.

Comment: That's at least what I assume from what I know about how default values work in other programming languages I have worked with. But maybe default values in R works differently?

Comment: 1 is indeed the default value for the parameter `nrow`, but it can tell whether `nrow` is 1 because you passed it in as such or because it was not passed in and defaulted to 1 by using the function `missing`.

Comment: Okay. So if I would want to create a wrapper function for `matrix` that would take the same arguments and just call `matrix` with those, is there some easy way I can do that in practice when function arguments of the wrapper function themselve can be missing? Or do I have to try every combination of missing/not missing for the incoming arguments and make the corresponding function call to `matrix` where I leave those arguments out (that would be 2^n different function calls if I have n arguments, hence it would grow exponentially)?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye It sounds like you've got an XY problem here where you've asked about something (default parameters for `matrix`) that isn't what you're actually trying to do. You would get a better answer if you asked more directly about your basic problem. Regardless, yes there is a way: just pass all of those parameters along to `matrix`, you don't have to check them at all.

Comment: @ChrisHaug You're probably right in that I've got an XY problem. I'm really just trying to wrap my head around the way that default argument values work in R, and why my intuition for how they should work doesn't hold. But you say that I can just pass the wrapper function arguments on? Interesting...